# Laravel sanctum SPA application with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have used front side javascript(jquery) and backend Laravel with sanctum. Backend side I have used a virtual host.

-> frontend - localhost/login.html

-> backend - http://alkmy.local/login

env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:S3rJd8xDyPMOjmuKIR28CFcFcJnMqEwO9A+xFzEZe+Q=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_DEBUG_bar=true
APP_URL=http://alkmy.local

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sanctum
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=vc@123

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

SESSION_DOMAIN=alkmy.local
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=alkmy.local
```

Issue
[image]

If I backend access using 'php artisan serve' and set bellow changes in .env then it works

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
```

Please Help how I can use laravel sanctum with a virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

its cros problem !

your app must be on same .tld.test

run your frontedapp on example.alkmy.local

[github](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/11)

Answer (score 0):

i'm working with laravel sanctum and using vue in front, maybe you have problem with cors, i mean, should be add in cors 'api/*' other problem maybe is that you lost the session... for fix this problem in vue we have a main.js file, like this

```
store.dispatch('getUser').then(() => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

here we use a store.dispatch('getUser')